# CSS spacing issue in Firefox Select Field

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having a spacing issue with CSS when using Firefox. This works fine in Chrome. When I have a form with fields and labels the line after a select field is getting extra space in front of it.

You can see the problem in the image here: http://i51.tinypic.com/35b8gmf.png . Where is the space in front of the text 'test2' coming from?

Here is the code:

```
<style>
label {
    float:left;
    width:70px;
}
input, select {
    width:130px;
}
</style>
<label for="l1">test1</label>
<select id="l1" name="test1"><option>a</option></select>
<br>
<label for="l2">test2</label>
<input id="l2" type="text" size="30" name="test2">
<br>
<label for="l3">test3</label>
<input id="l3" type="text" size="30" name="test3">
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox? What's your platform Windows or Mac? What DOCTYPE are you targetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
label {
    float:left;
    width:70px;
}
input, select {
    width:130px;
}
</style>
<label for="l1">test1</label>
<select id="l1" name="test1"><option>a</option></select>
<br style="clear:both;">
<label for="l2">test2</label>
<input id="l2" type="text" size="30" name="test2">
<br style="clear:both;">
<label for="l3">test3</label>
<input id="l3" type="text" size="30" name="test3">
<div id="tests">asd</div>
```